# What is the intuition behind the result that the speed which maximizes range > speed that maximizes time spent airborne for a plane resisting air?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Consider a flying airplane. Assume total air resistance is composed of a force that is proportional to $v^2$ and another force inversely proportional to $v^2$ (induced drag) as follows:

$$F_{air}=\alpha v^2 + \frac{\beta}{v^2}, \alpha, \beta>0\tag{1}$$

The plane's engines generate force to exactly offset air resistance.

What speed $v$ maximizes the time the plane is in the air, and what speed $v$ maximizes the distance the plane flies, assuming a given amount of fuel?

My questions relate to the solution, which is as follows.

The fuel can be thought of as containing a fixed amount of energy that will be used as work. Let's call the fixed amount $W_0$.

The total work done by the engines is

$$W_0=R(v)\cdot F(v)\tag{2}$$

where $R$ is range and $F$ has magnitude equal to $F_{air}$. Also,

$$R=v\cdot t(v)\tag{3}$$

Note that $t$ is a function of $v$, implicitly defined in eq $(2)$.

Therefore we have

$$W_0=R(v)\cdot F(v)=v\cdot t(v)\cdot (\alpha v^2 + \frac{\beta}{v^2})\tag{4}$$

Another way to look at it is
$$W_0=(Fv)t=Pt\tag{5}$$

where $P$ is power.

To find $v$ that maximizes R, we differentiate $(4)$ with respect to $v$, with $\frac{dW_0}{dv}=0$ (because $W_0$ is constant) and $\frac{dR}{dv}=0$ (because we want the critical point of $R(v)$).

$$\frac{dW_0}{dv}=\frac{dR}{dv}F_{air}(v)+R(v)\frac{dF_{air}}{dv}$$
$$R(v)\frac{dF_{air}}{dv}=0$$
$$\frac{dF_{air}}{dv}=0$$

The speed that maximizes range is the speed that minimizes air resistance.

On the other hand, if we want to maximize time spent flying we have

$$W_0=v\cdot t(v) \cdot F_{air}(v)$$
$$t(v)=\frac{W_0}{v\cdot F_{air}(v)}$$

We could differentiate $t(v)$ and set to zero or realize that maximizing $t(v)$ entails minimizing the denominator, so

$$\frac{d(v\cdot F_{air}(v))}{dv}=0$$

The denominator happens to be power, so we need to minimize power to maximize time spent airborne.

It is intuitive to me that by minimizing time rate of work (ie power), you maximize the time it takes to do the fixed amount of work represented by the fuel. It is not that intuitive that the speed which minimizes power is not the same as the speed which minimizes the force the engine must produce (to counter the corresponding minimum level of air resistance).

Note that the first order conditions were

$$F_{air}'=2\alpha v - \frac{2\beta}{v^3}=0$$
$$(v\cdot F_{air}(v))'=F_{air}+vF_{air}'=\alpha v^2+\frac{\beta}{v^2}+v\left( 2\alpha v - \frac{2\beta}{v^3} \right)$$

The second expression is larger than the first expression (at least when $v$ is larger than 1, on a quick glance), so the second expression crosses the $v$ axis at a smaller $v$, let's call it $v_2$.

The crossing of the first expression represents the smallest air resistance, and it happens at $v_1$; the crossing of the second expression represents the lowest power. As we move from the $v_2$ to $v_1$, force decreases, and speed increases, but the speed must increase more than force such that power increases too.

My doubt is about the intuition behind this.

Comment: What is the intuition behind the second component of your drag force? The force is infinite when the plane is at rest?

Comment: @nasu from where I saw this particular problem, the induced drag force only occurs when there is wind flowing along the wings. Therefore, I imagine this is a force that only comes up when there is some lower threshold of relative speed between wings and air. It is "induced" drag after all. Fyi, if you'd like to see the actual problem, it is challenge problem 6.94 of chapter 6 of the book University Physics, 6th Ed.

Comment: By what author?

Comment: Young and Freedman @nasu

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking for intuition, I will keep the explanation very basic.

The average speed is defined as the range divided by the time spent airborne.

So you are asking why maximizing the numerator gives you a larger number than maximizing the denominator.

It isn't necessarily true, but it seems intuitively obvious before doing any calculations.

Comment: The intuition you just gave is purely mathematical in nature. There are multiple ways to see that intuition. I provided another one in the question when I showed the expressions for the two first order conditions. However, I am asking for the intuition in terms of the physics concepts of forces, work, and power. I actually asked another question that sort of isolates one of my main doubts about the concept of power, and it is related to this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/667254/does-a-constant-force-generated-by-fuel-consumption-offset-by-an-opposite-forc

Comment: suggest you post this on the aviation stack exchange and get an explanation from one of the aerodynamicists there. I believe what you are missing is the relationship between drag force and speed.