# Does a constant force, generated by fuel consumption, offset by an opposite force, applied to a mass with speed v, consume more fuel if v increased?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Consider a system composed of a mass moving with speed v along an axis $x$. Consider what happens if two forces $F_1$ and $F_2$ of equal magnitude and opposite direction are applied to the mass.

The resultant force is zero, but we can calculate the work done by each of the individual forces, between two points $x_1$ and $x_2$, e.g.

$$W_1=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} F_1 dx$$

Each force does work of equal magnitude but opposite sign between the two points.

Consider now the instantaneous power output $P_1=F_1 v$, which is constant because both $F_1$ and $v$ are constant.

My question is the following.

Imagine that $F_1$ is generated by a mechanism that relies on fuel. At this point in my learning, I understand that fuel represents energy that will be used to perform work (I am not sure if this wording is correct, because I don't think energy "performs" work, forces do), and thus there is a fixed amount of work that can be done by $F_1$, which we assume is constant until the fuel ends.

By changing the speed of the object on which $F_1$ acts we change the power output of $F_1$. If we increase the speed, the time rate of work increases as well, and my conclusion is that the fuel will be consumed faster.

But the magnitude of $F_1$ did not change, and nothing is happening to the mass either (because we assume $F_2$ offsets $F_1$ exactly, though I am not sure that this assumption is useful or makes anything different. I just used it to form a scenario where nothing changes except the initial constant speed of the mass, yet the fuel consumption would go up if my reasoning about power output is correct).

Is my reasoning about fuel consumption correct in this example?

Comment: This question cannot be answered as a general question. You need to specify the mechanism. Different mechanisms (e.g. rocket vs car) will lead to different answers. Also, you need to specify if the different velocities represent the same scenario from different reference frames or different scenarios (e.g. velocity relative to ground)

Comment: Ok. The reason I am asking is to try to understand work and power a bit better. It's not a problem to make assumptions in an answer, I simply don't know what the assumptions could be, so it would actually be interesting to read answers with different assumptions. For example, why would a car be different from a rocket? I am assuming that you aren't referring to things like heat and sound; I think including such details would get away from the focus which is the core concepts of work and power. With regard to reference frame, I think that this gets to the crux of my question which is

Comment: does the speed of the object affect the calculation of power, and does power affect the calculation of how fast fuel is consumed. Because if the answers are yes and yes, then doesn't fuel consumption then depend on choice of reference frame?

Comment: if the reference frame thing is the crux of the question then you should edit the question to state it explicitly. I will answer accordingly in the meantime.

Comment: You brought up the reference frame perspective. I think that is perhaps another way to state my question, in other terms. Namely, does the speed of the object affect fuel consumption in the scenario above, where speed changes but force doesn't. Whether speed changes within the same reference frame or we just use a different speed because the reference frame changed is something which you brought up and I find interesting. I guess my original question is probably just referring to two situations, both viewed from the same reference frame, and the only change is speed, and the doubt is about

Comment: if the power changed then does that mean the fuel consumption changed even though there was no change to the force applied?

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify the type of vehicle under consideration here, and it does make a difference. So I will answer assuming an automobile driving on a level road at constant speed in still air. We will consider only thrust from the wheel and air resistance and ignore all other inefficiencies and effects.

Now, as you mention $P=\vec F \cdot \vec v$ where $\vec v$ is the velocity of the material at the point of application of $\vec F$. So, for a car the thrust $\vec F_T=\vec F$ is applied at the bottom point of the tire where it meets the road, and at that point $\vec v_T=0$ in the usual reference frame of the ground. So $P_T = \vec F_T \cdot \vec v_T = 0$ and the force from the ground provides no power. In contrast, for the drag from the air $\vec F_A=-\vec F$ is applied to the automobile itself which is moving at $\vec v_A$ where the vectors are pointed in the opposite direction so $P_A = \vec F_A \cdot \vec v_A = - F v_A <0$.

So, the power consumed by the engine (neglecting inefficiencies) is $P = P_T + P_A = -F v_A$ which represents a decrease in energy of the auto due to expending the fuel. The energy goes from the auto into the air. Note that no energy is provided by the road and the force at the tire does no work. All is as expected.

Now, let's consider the same scenario from a reference frame where the ground is moving at $\vec u$. In this case $P_T = \vec F_T \cdot \vec u = \vec F \cdot \vec u$ and $P_A = \vec F_A \cdot (\vec v_A + \vec u) = -\vec F \cdot (\vec v_A + \vec u)$.

So the power consumed by the engine in this frame is $P=P_T + P_A = \vec F \cdot \vec u -\vec F \cdot (\vec v_A + \vec u) = -F v_A $. Again the energy of the auto decreases by the same amount and so the same amount of fuel is expended in all reference frames. However, note that in this frame energy is provided by the road and the force at the tire does work. $P_T = \vec F_T \cdot \vec u \ne 0$. All is not as expected. Where is this extra work from the ground coming from? Where is the ground getting the energy?

The KE of the earth is $KE_{earth} = \frac{1}{2} M_{earth} v_{earth}^2$. In the frame of the ground $v_{earth}=0$ so $KE_{earth}=0$, but in the frame where the ground is moving at $\vec u$ we have $KE_{earth}=\frac{1}{2} M_{earth} u^2$ which, since $M_{earth}$ is so large is a huge reservoir of KE. The force at the road transfers a small amount of this huge KE to the road. That is the source of the extra work from the ground.

This work from the KE of the earth is what is used so that although the power of each individual force changes from frame to frame, the overall fuel consumption does not change.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129874/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-does-a-constant-force-generated-by-fuel-consumptio).

Answer (score 0):

If the driving force remains constant, then it does deliver more power at a higher speed, but traveling a given distance requires less time, and power times time gives work (which is force times distance).  The work done (and fuel used) for a given displacement would be the same at any speed.  However, you would also need to considered the work required to increase the kinetic energy of the moving mass.  And, if $F_2$ were from fluid friction, then both forces would increase with speed, requiring more work be done.

Comment: You argued that if we increase speed, then power output of the constant force increases, and thus for work done on a certain displacement previously, the same work can be done in a smaller displacement in the new setup. Which means that if you keep the displacement constant, the work done increases. When you say "the work done (and fuel used) for a given displacement would be the same at any speed", I don't know how to reconcile this with how I interpreted what you said before that: namely, that power increased because speed increased.

Comment: Assuming constant forces and speed, the work done for a given displacement is independent of the speed.  In other situations, things get more complicated.